# Google Firebase Vs Amazon AWS for complex queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, react-native, instagram

I'm currently working on a react-native project similar to Instagram using Firebase Real-time database and Storage. I was considering switching to Amazon AWS as with firebase complex queries are not supported. Does Amazon AWS provide something more or should I just stick with Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon AWS is much more complex I would say, it also requires more experience. If you don't have huge data on background and Firebase has all features which you are planning to use, stay on Firebase.